# Expected Value and Variance of Two Random Variable

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m$ be independent exponential distributed random samples with mean $\theta$. Let $T\alpha = \alpha\bar{x} + (1-\alpha)\bar{y}$, where $0 < \alpha < 1$.

a) Find $E[T\alpha]$ and $var(T\alpha)$

b) Show that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, $P\big(|T\alpha - \theta| > \epsilon\big) \to 0$ as $m, n \to \infty$.

For part a I tried using the conventional way of finding the expected value for $T\alpha$ using the integral function, but with two different variables I am quite stuck.

For part B, I have no clue what it is asking, and how to start.

Need advice and help~!!! Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $T\alpha$, that is, $T$ multiplied by the real number $\alpha$, rather than $T_\alpha$, a random variable that is a linear combination of the $X_i$ and the $Y_i$?

Comment: Yes exactly what you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:  $\displaystyle E\left[\sum_{i=i}^m a_i Z_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i E[Z_i]$ for random variables whose expectations are defined, and for independent random variables with finite variances, $\displaystyle \operatorname{var}\left(\sum_{i=i}^m a_i Z_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i^2\operatorname{var}(Z_i).$

Comment: I thought expected value for exponential distribution should be an integral. Also, according to that it should be 
E[T_a] = a*E[sample mean of X] + (1-a)E(sample mean of Y)?